# Is it possible to send a message in channel @mention user

Tags: microsoft-teams

I'm trying to send a message in channel, I did'nt found any sample code for that.
I want @mention a user in channel message, is it possible through graph API or bot?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/conversation-basics?tabs=dotnet

I tried to pass the channel id for SendConversationAsync Method.
it throws exception. Bot conversation not found.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to @mention using either [a bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/bot-v3/bot-conversations/bots-conv-channel#constructing-mentions) or using [Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post-messages?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#example-2-).

With regards your "SendConversationAsync", you'd need to post a code sample or similar, but it sounds like you're trying to do Proactive Messaging, and there are certain properties and setup required for that to work properly. Please see here for more: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-proactive-messaging#:~:text=A%20proactive%20message%20is%20a,user%20is%20a%20member%20of](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-proactive-messaging#:%7E:text=A%20proactive%20message%20is%20a,user%20is%20a%20member%20of).

Comment: Thanks , i will try that

Comment: Keep us posted how it goes